# How to connect to two different database in ef core database first

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

How to create two different database context to use two different database in EF core. i am using database first approach.

Currently using the following line to use in my startup.cs

```
builderModel.Services.AddDbContext<DB1Context>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DB1Context")));
```

Thanks

Comment: What's keeping you from doing the same thing you did for DB1Context and just name it DB2Context?

Comment: Are you getting any errors doing the obvious (copy and inherit)?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds pretty straight forward (if DBs are already set up and equal in schema). Try

```
builderModel.Services.AddDbContext<DB1Context>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DB1Context")));

builderModel.Services.AddDbContext<DB2Context>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DB2Context")));
```

And as a bonus, you can inherit from the existing DbContext you already have (because it's the same code).

Answer (score 0):

so if i understand you correctly: with your "Startup-Line" you add the first (DB1Context) Context to the "program", if you have 2 DbContexts you 
obviously need 2 of these (same for DB2).

now you can migrate it by using the  nuget-package-console(google it if you never 
heared of it^^) and write : 
Add-migration mymigration -context:Db1Context 
Add-migration mymigration -context:Db2Context

*Mymigration is the name of the *.cs(in this case: Mymigration.cs) file which is used for the creation/update of the database, you could also give it a different name.
it also creates a folder calles "migration" where the *.cs file is stored

After that you have to update your database with the comment:

update-database

Than you should have 2(or at least 2 upgraded) new Tables in your Database.

IF add migrtion doesnt work, make shure you picked the correct Project (where the contexts are located)

I aslo have to admit that i never tried to migrate 2 Contexts, but in theory thats the way to do it....
This is my first answer on Stackoverflow so i hope i could help you :D